# Default ASP.NET Identity login redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-templates

In the default Visual Studio 2013 MVC SPA template, all requests default to a login page, except for the help page. I assume this is due to that having a seperate controller.

Where is the code located that requires a login for all other pages?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `[Authorize]` attribute ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)): eg if you had these controllers

```
[Authorize]
public class SecureController
{
    public ActionResult Index() {}
}

public class HelpController
{
    public ActionResult Index() {}
}
```

Then browsing to /Secure would redirect to the login page, but browsing to /Help would not

Comment: I wondered if that was it, but the HomeController class does not have this attribute applied unfortunately